# Please explain me how this output is coming?

Tags: java

```
class Vehicle{
  Vehicle(){
    System.out.println("Vehicle Constructor Invoked");
  }
}

public class Car extends Vehicle{
  Car(){
    System.out.println("Car Constructor Invoked");
  }
  {
    System.out.println("Anonymous Block Invoked");
  }
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Car c=new Car();
  }
}
```

## output

Vehicle Constructor Invoked
Anonymous Block Invoked
Car Constructor Invoked

Comment: What is it about this that is causing you confusion?

Comment: Read this article https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5

Answer (score 0):

First, the superclass constructor is called, `Vehicle` in this case. 
Then, the anonymous block is executed, it is set of commands that is "appended" at the beginning of all constructors. Finally the actual constructor from `Car` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

It's hopefully obvious if you look at what the compiler turns this code into:

```
class Vehicle{
  Vehicle(){
    super();
    System.out.println("Vehicle Constructor Invoked");
  }
}

public class Car extends Vehicle{
  Car(){
    // First the super constructor is invoked. If you don't invoke it explicitly, the compiler adds the call.
    super();

    // Then, instance initializers are inlined into any constructor invoking `super`, after the super.
    System.out.println("Anonymous Block Invoked");

    // Then, the rest of the constructor body.
    System.out.println("Car Constructor Invoked");
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
    Car c=new Car();
  }
}
```

You can see this if you decompile the code, e.g. with `javap`.